# Реализация фильтрации по параметрам контроллера

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller

Подскажите пожалуйста как элегантно решить такую проблему: имеется GET Controller, который принимает несколько параметров, но параметры эти не обязательны, т.е как в примере ниже, придет дата, значит вызвать метод repository с фильтрацией по дате, имеется сортировка, значит метод с сортировкой. Я еще только учусь, по этому направъте пожалуйста в нужную сторону.

```java
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public Collection<EmployeeDTO> getEmployeeByCompany(@RequestParam("manager_id") String managerId,
                                                        @RequestParam("company_id") String companyId,
                                                        @RequestParam("sort_by_employee") boolean sortByEmployee,
                                                        @RequestParam("date_work_from") LocalDate dateFrom,
                                                        @RequestParam("sort_by_date") boolean sortByDate) {
        //some code
    }
```

Comment: У аннотации `@RequestParam` есть параметр `requaired`. Ставьте его в `false` и параметр будет не обязательный. Но тогда рекомендую сделать `defaultValue`. Воспользуйтесь `if`-ами что бы вызывать то что Вам нужно.

Comment: Но это должен быть один контроллер или под каждый набор параметров свой контроллер? Или в одном, к примеру, 5 if?

Comment: Можно и в одном, но если в будущем Вы планируете добавлять фильтры, то тут я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону `DTO`-шек. И возможно разных контроллеров.

Comment: я так понимаю, что параметры могут быть разные и давать различные комбинации... в этом случае очень скоро наступает комбинаторный взрыв. условные операторы в таком случае - плохое решение. почитайте про паттерн декоратор и цепочка обязанностей. есть единый интерфейс и наследники, каждый из которых выполняют конктерную одну функцию, например один класс делает сортировку по дате и т.д. мало того, в случае с цепочкой обязанностей каждый класс знает, когда отрабатывать , а когда нет ( например,класс,который сортирует по дате,сам проверяет есть ли дата).очень просто и никакого комбинаторного взрыва

Comment: очень интересно, Дмитрий, но пока что не понял как это реализовать!

Comment: паттерн декоратор и цепочка обязанностей, безусловно крутая штука, и в сервисе, код конечно становиться приятнее, но самым элегантным для моей проблемы решением я нашел: построение динамических sql запросов при помощи фреймворка Querydsl! https://rieckpil.de/howto-dynamic-sql-querying-pagination-with-querydsl-and-spring-data-jpa/